# Execute processed string

Tags: bash, sed, eval

I tried the following to change the slashes and proceed to the folder, but it is not working:

```
 # change the backward slashes to forward
 cmd_str="echo 'cd c:\\test\\folderA\\C\\' | sed 's/\\/\//g'"
 # execute the processed string, goto folder
 eval "cd $cmd_str"
```

It states:

```
 -bash: cd: echo: No such file or directory
 sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Another question is, how may I take in parameters for the path string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `eval`. Use `cd` directly, with a [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to perform the replacement of  `\` chars. with `/`:

```
dir='c:\test\folderA\C\'
cd "${dir//\\//}"
```

This approach also allows you to pass the dir. path as an argument and assign it as `dir=$1`, for instance.